# html.haml to html.erb converter for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, converters, haml, erb

I inherited a bunch of `html.haml` views in Rails project and want them to be `html.erb`.

Could you suggest some automatic Rails-aware converter?

Everything I've found is a set of HTML to HAML converters that additionally do not understand Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this converter to convert manually, link below

https://haml2erb.org/

I don't think any automatic html to erb converter is available as of now!